# LibGDX - Multiple Console errors in TexureRegion

Tags: java, libgdx

Heres the main chunk of code. All I'm trying to do is get a simple image to be displayed as the background of the game and after 10 hours of research I still can't get it to get it to work.

```
public class SlingshotSteve implements ApplicationListener {
   // Creates our 2D images
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private TextureRegion backgroundTexture;


@Override
public void create() {


    new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
    backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(backgroundTexture, 20, 20, 50, 50);

}


@Override
public void render() {  
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0); 
      batch.end();

}
```

Heres the Console error that I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:118)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.<init>(TextureRegion.java:70)
at com.dakotapederson.slingshotsteve.SlingshotSteve.create(SlingshotSteve.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

I'm new at this and I'm taking this slow so please explain the issue with as much clarity as possible.

Comment: Dimensions of the "background.jpg"? It mmust be 2^n*2^n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You something missed, here is how your code should look like:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));
backgroundTexture = new TextureRegion(texture, 20, 20, 50, 50);
```